# add target blank on custom php code

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

How can I open a link in another window?

```
<?php if(get_option_tree('rss')) { ?>
<a href="<?php get_option_tree('rss',$theme_options,'true'); ?>" id="rss" title="RSS" class="tt_top"></a><?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add `target="_blank"` [to the 'a' tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)